# Remove rows having swapped columns in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have table with 10 columns but we need 3 columns to be considered

### Id           from_value        to_value

1234      ABC                   CDR
1234      CDR                   ABC
3456      XYZ                   PQR

### 3456      PQR                   XYZ

OUTPUT should be:

### Id           from_value        to_value

1234      ABC                   CDR

### 3456      XYZ                   PQR

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,from_value,to_value
FROM (
SELECT id,from_value,to_value,row_number() over (partition by id order by timecol desc) as row_num 
from table) table
    WHERE row_num = 1
```

U need to use windowing and row num to achieve this.
U may relace your time colums